# Python tk: Put a button over a notebook widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tk-toolkit

Is it possible to place a button over a notebook widget? Here is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = Tk()
note = ttk.Notebook(root)

b = Button(root, text="OK")
b.pack()

tab1 = Frame(note)
tab2 = Frame(note)
tab3 = Frame(note)
Button(tab1, text='Exit', command=root.destroy).pack(padx=100, pady=100)

note.add(tab1, text = "Tab One")
note.add(tab2, text = "Tab Two")
note.add(tab3, text = "Tab Three")
note.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "over a notebook".  Do you mean place the "Exit" button on each tab of the notebook?

Comment: That, or right at the end of it ([example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29210231/Untitled.png)).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, well, in that case, I would recommend one of two options.  First is to make the button its own tab like so:

```
from tkinter import *
# This does the same thing
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
note = ttk.Notebook(root)

b = Button(root, text="OK")
b.pack()

tab1 = Frame(note)
tab2 = Frame(note)
tab3 = Frame(note)
tab4 = Button(root, text="Exit Application?", command=root.destroy)

note.add(tab1, text = "Tab One")
note.add(tab2, text = "Tab Two")
note.add(tab3, text = "Tab Three")
note.add(tab4, text = "Exit")
note.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

or, second, use the `grid` method to precisely place the widgets:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
note = ttk.Notebook(root)

b = Button(root, text="OK")
b.grid()

tab1 = Frame(note)
tab2 = Frame(note)
tab3 = Frame(note)
Button(root, text='Exit', command=root.destroy).grid(row=1, column=1)

note.add(tab1, text = "Tab One")
note.add(tab2, text = "Tab Two")
note.add(tab3, text = "Tab Three")
note.grid(row=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Note however that the second option will require you to adjust the grid settings depending on how many widgets you have and where you place them.  You will also have to deal with resizing.  However, the method is more common.  But, in the end, it all comes down to your preference.

Comment: Oh, I meant actually on the tab, like, by the "Tab One", "Tab Two", and "Tab Three" text, or just like right [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29210231/Untitled.png) in the image (the red circle).

Comment: @user2638731 - Oh, I was confused.  See my new post.  Hope it helps.